# Does apache log client IPs

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, logging, network-monitoring

Does apache log client IPs per request by default? If not, what are some common ways to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't, and why haven't you done some cursory research?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Apache logs the IP addresses that request resources from it. By default, the logs are stored in `/var/log/apache2/access.log`, but you can check your Apache config file at `/etc/apache2/sites-available/your site` under the `CustomLog` directive.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does. Please read http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#accesslog for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does by default as much as i know. We dont have to do any special configuration to get client ips in apache's access_log. it comes by default